# Roslyn CTP to RTM upgrade - How to use formatter

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

In CTP version, I used to write below code to save the changes to file with the formatting. Any idea what is changed in RTM?

```
 IEnumerable<IFormattingRule> rules =  FormattingRules.GetDefaultRules("C#");
            File.WriteAllText(
                filePath,
                modifiedTree.Format(FormattingOptions.GetDefaultOptions(), rules).GetFormattedRoot().ToFullString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [`Formatter.Format`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/Formatting/Formatter.cs#L177).